# PHP: rand() or array_rand trouble

Tags: php, random

Results in result2.txt repeats every ~100 string. 
Yes, same surnames and same rand(100000, 999999) results are cycling every 100 values

NetBeans 8.0.2

```
//Get surname
$famtxt = file('surname.txt');
$surname = $famtxt[ array_rand($famtxt) ]; 
unset($famtxt); 

//Results
$result0=$surname.' '.rand(100000, 999999);                               
$resulttxt = fopen('result2.txt', 'a');
fwrite($resulttxt,$result0);
```

Comment: @DeDee it sounds like OP is saying his "random" results are cycling every 100 values or so, which isn't generally what you want when generating random numbers.

Comment: @Ярослав OK, could you edit your question slightly, in any way, so I can remove my downvote?

Comment: @DeDee, done. Sorry, I'm not very good in English language, but do not know the site better than stackoverflow

Comment: I just performed `for ($i=1; $i<=10000; $i++) echo rand(100000, 999999)."<br />"` and only 45 out of 10000 results were duplicates.

Comment: @DeDee use mt_rand(100000, 999999); instead, and you will get 0 duplicates out of 10000 :p also ++$i  is faster than $i++. and no, php is not smart enough to auto optimize this for you (unlike most other languages) - and here is a test script - http://pastebin.com/11qJu0k7

Comment: @hanshenrik I intentionally used `rand` to see if duplicates would occur as often as the asker said. My test ruled out the `rand` being a problem.

Comment: ^ depends on the libc used. linux has very different libc from Windows, and XP is different from win7/vista, and so on. i guess you ran your test on an old linux or an old windows OS? :p

Comment: @hanshenrik Nope, on a phpfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `rand`, there are better functions out there, namely

http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php

> Generates cryptographic random integers that are suitable for use
>   where unbiased results are critical (e.g. shuffling a Poker deck).

or

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

> Many random number generators of older libcs have dubious or unknown
>   characteristics and are slow. By default, PHP uses the libc random
>   number generator with the rand() function. The mt_rand() function is a
>   drop-in replacement for this. **It uses a random number generator with
>   known characteristics using the »  Mersenne Twister**, which will
>   produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc
>   rand() provides.

(Emphasis added by me) The speed is a nice bonus, but the fact that its using `MT` will give you "randomer" numbers than just `rand`.

Comment: Ty, but still cycling results

Comment: "still cycling results", is mt_rand() cycling results? how did you come to that conclusion? how are you testing this?

Comment: wrote a test script here, and at 1 million iterations, it seems to cycle nothing in my results (a few numbers at 10 times and 9 times at the range 100000, 999999 ) - how about you? http://pastebin.com/11qJu0k7

Comment: @hanshenrik, ty mate, but it was great trolling by my NetBeans IDE

Answer (score 0):

AWW!
It was just a terrible NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 trouble with pseudorandom generator. 
Script works fine on a server

Comment: No. you're using a crapy libc with a crappy rand on your dev computer (microsoft's msvcrt maybe?) , while the server you're using has a good libc with a good rand().

Comment: @hanshenrik, you think my libc are SO bad? :/ so, you may suggest what to do? I like NetBeans IDE, I do not want to leave it :с

Comment: the problem is not NetBeans, it is the c runtime it loads from your operating system (windows XP? windows 7? Mac? Mac OS X? Linux? whatever it runs in.) for me, it loads the c runtime and rand() from C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll on windows 7 x64 SP1

Comment: the point is, the c runtime library on your computer, probably has a bad implementation of rand() (are you using windows XP perhaps? :p )

Comment: @hanshenrik C runtime library ruining work of my PHP - oooh, i love programming so much!!!
I using x64 Win8, and can found msvcrt.dll, but what I need to do with it?
Update? Delete? Rewrite? ;)
I think i need latest version of this libc, but where it is?