# How to generate a random number from a uniform distribution in php?

Tags: php, random, uniform-distribution

I am trying to generate a random number from a uniform distribution in php using `$group = rand(0,8)`. I ran my experiment around 200 times and I get the following distribution which suggests that all groups do not have an equal probability of being selected.

```
Group |  Freq.    Percent      Cum.
------+------------------------------
0     |  20        9.52        9.52
1     |   4        1.90       11.43
2     |  25       11.90       23.33
3     |  32       15.24       38.57
4     |  27       12.86       51.43
5     |  22       10.48       61.90
6     |  30       14.29       76.19
7     |  24       11.43       87.62
8     |  26       12.38      100.00
------+-------------------------------
Total |  210      100.00
```

I read the discussion thread here [PHP: rand() or array_rand trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428951/php-rand-or-array-rand-trouble) and the only reason I ask this question is because I am new to php and don't know whether I should use:

- random_int() http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php
- stats_rand_gen_iuniform() http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-rand-gen-iuniform.php
- or anything else?

Comment: Any random integer function in does provide a uniform distribution, *perhaps* with the exception of `stats_rand_gen_iuniform()` but these functions are highly undocumented and requires you to install the pear stats package. You can however make your own functions, checking the occurrences `array_count_values()` vs `sizeof()` array to determine if the random integer deserves a re roll.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need cryptographically-secure random, use [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) ("mt" stands for [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)). It works faster and should have better statistical characteristics.

```
function testRand($randFunction, $groupsNumber = 10, $rollsNumber = 210)
{
    $frequencies = array_fill(0, $groupsNumber, 0);
    foreach (range(1, $rollsNumber) as $ignored) {
        $frequencies[$randFunction(0, $groupsNumber - 1)]++;
    }

    echo PHP_EOL, "------- results for `$randFunction` -------", PHP_EOL;
    $cum = 0;
    foreach ($frequencies as $index => $frequency) {
        $percent = $frequency * 100 / $rollsNumber;
        $cum += $percent;
        echo sprintf("%d\t|\t%4d\t%6.2f\t%6.2f", 
                     $index, $frequency, $percent, $cum), 
             PHP_EOL;
    }
}

testRand('rand');
testRand('mt_rand');

// I don't have PHP 7 or stats package handy. Uncomment if you do
// testRand('random_int'); 
// testRand('stats_rand_gen_iuniform');
```

Output:

```
------- results for `rand` -------
0   |     26     12.38   12.38
1   |     20      9.52   21.90
2   |     18      8.57   30.48
3   |     21     10.00   40.48
4   |     25     11.90   52.38
5   |     12      5.71   58.10
6   |     26     12.38   70.48
7   |     14      6.67   77.14
8   |     19      9.05   86.19
9   |     29     13.81  100.00

------- results for `mt_rand` -------
0   |     17      8.10    8.10
1   |     25     11.90   20.00
2   |     21     10.00   30.00
3   |     20      9.52   39.52
4   |     18      8.57   48.10
5   |     18      8.57   56.67
6   |     25     11.90   68.57
7   |     23     10.95   79.52
8   |     21     10.00   89.52
9   |     22     10.48  100.00
```

As a side note, 210 is pretty small sampling, so eventually you would see "bad" results with any random number generator.